# how to install numpy for already installed python 3.8.1 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, ubuntu-18.04, numpy-ndarray

I have three versions of python 2.7 , 3.6 and 3.8.
I installed "numpy" on 3.8 many times but does not work on jupyter notebook.
Any thing will be great help because i have a task to submit tonight

```
linux commands 
> sudo apt update
> sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
> sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv
> mkdir ~/my_project_dir
> cd ~/my_project_dir
```

> and here i ran a single command to install jupyter notebook , which i forgot but it was suggested to me by the terminal

Comment: You might be launching notebook pointing toward some other module directory, I would suggest using anaconda.

Comment: can we use anaconda on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @8hubham - download and install anaconda from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/).

Then in your terminal, you can create a virtual environment where you can choose your specific version of python (3.8):

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.8
```

Then activate the virtual environment:

```
conda activate myenv
```

You can pip install `numpy` now:

```
pip install numpy
```

Now with pip install `ipykernel` and `jupyter`:

```
pip install ipykernel
pip install jupyter
```

Finally, install a kernel for your virtual env:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv
```

When you launch a Jupyter notebook server from your terminal within the virtual environment you just set up `("myenv")`, you should see your `myenv`kernel in the drop-down menu when setting up a new notebook:

jupyter notebook server new notebook with myenv kernel:

[image: jupyter notebook server new notebook with myenv kernel]

Comment: shouldnt it be pip3 instead of pip bcuz i want python 3

Comment: You'll be fine using pip as you're specifying the python version when setting up the virtual env. The packages that you install when inside your virtual env will all be compatible with that python version.

Comment: i've downloaded anaconda , its some .sh file , is that how its supposed to  be not zip file?

Comment: also for conda create --name myenv python=3.8 it says command not found

Comment: Yep that's fine, now you'll want to cd into your Downloads directory (or wherever you downloaded to) and run the .sh script:

`bash Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh`

The `conda create` command will only work when anaconda is installed.

Comment: conda create still says command not found. i put .sh file on desktop , did cd Desktop and ran your command ,waited for installation.

Comment: Did you follow all of the steps after launching the installer and were there any error messages? What is the name of your .sh file on your desktop?

Comment: .sh file name: Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh

Comment: i just kept on pressing enter where ever it paused

Comment: it  says my anaconda3 is installed in home, i go to home on my terminal and run conda  create but still no use. Should i go into that specific folder and then run conda command

Comment: Try running `source <path to conda>/bin/activate` (where the <path to conda> is where conda was installed, probably /home/user/anaconda3) and then run `conda init`

Comment: hey it works , thank you soooo much , really!! just one more thing , if i close the terminal , at which place should i write jupyter notebook that my "myenv" opens with it

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your assignment! If you close the terminal you will need to reopen it and activate the virtual env again. Then if you cd into the directory you saved your notebook in you can use the command `jupyter notebook` to start the jupyter server in the location of your notebook.